# SSIS package hangs when trying to load more than 50K records from Agent job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SQL Server 2016 package which has been deployed SSIS catalog and has been scheduled to run through SQL Server agent job.
The package has a DFT which does an UPSERT operation with both the source and destination SQL server DB.
The package runs absolutely fine from SSDT for any number of rows.
The issue is when running through Agent job, it fails when the source has more than 50K records.
When the number of rows is reduced to 50K or low, it runs fine.
SQL Server and SSIS are on the same machine which has a total of 32GB RAM out of which 20GB has been allocated to SQL Server with no other major software installed on it.
I had used temporary tables to perform bulk updates but to debug the issue I removed and just kept the insert branch, but the issue still persists.
I am not sure what is causing this issue as SSIS can load millions of records without any problem.

Comment: You say it fails when there are more than 50,000 rows, but you forgot to include  the error. That's going to be very important here.

Comment: There's no UPSERT operation or target. I suspect you're using a command that performs a MERGE or UPDATE ... INSERT row-by-row. Did you check Activity Monitor to see what's going on? Such an operation will *always* be slow though. It's a *lot* faster to insert records into a staging table and update the target table with UPDATE and INSERT statements. If you know which rows are new in advance, you can insert them directly to the target

Comment: The SQL Server destinations use bulk insert mechanisms to perform inserts as fast as possible with minimal logging. That alone makes them a *lot* faster than executing 50K INSERT statements one by one

Comment: Sorry, My bad!! I have edited the question. Actually the DFT does not fail but just gets stuck. I checked in the integration services catalog execution report which does not have any errors. The last event which I see is an "OnInformation" event which says the pre-execute phase is beginning. This is just after lookup has cached 0 rows (As first time insert).

Comment: @panagiotis-kanavos, I have used fast load option in the OLEDB destination. The main issue is there is some threshold around 48k-50k which when breached freezes the package. If the number of records is 47k, it would execute in 2 seconds.

Comment: @Shaggy1755 there's no UPSERT destination. The OLEDB destination performs a BULK INSERT. Check *Activity Monitor* in SSMS to see what's going on in the database, not the reports. Is your query blocked and by whom? Is there a lot of IO perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to activity monitor which I have been requesting. But yeah, I can ask from the DBA to check for the blocked query. Thanks!!!